# How to sort data in listview in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, sorting, listview

Can you help me please to sort data in listView?
 
The listView is linked with Firebase DataBase,
I want to sort them by time, meaning that the last data that is added to Firebase appears first in the listview.
Please excuse me, I'm still a beginner in Android Studio.

I'm using this code to get the data from Firebase Database

```
ListView listLocation;
DatabaseReference databaseLocation;
List<Location> locationList;

    @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseLocation.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            locationList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot locationSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){

                Location location = locationSnapshot.getValue(Location.class);

                locationList.add(location);
            }
            LocationList adapter = new LocationList(getActivity(), locationList);

            Collections.reverse((List<LocationList>) adapter);

            listLocation.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It becomes a little difficult when you're not explaining how would you like to sort your collection. But i this case i'm assuming you're trying to sort by the `distance.`

So the code snippets would be as below.

```
  Collections.sort(adapter, new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            Location l1 = (Location) o1;
            Location l2 = (Location) o2;
            return l1.getDistance().compareTo(l2.getDistance());
        }
    });
```

We're making a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) that can compare your objects, or if they are all instances of the same class, you can make that class implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). You can then use Collections.sort() to do the actual sorting.

Comment: thank you so much sir , I forgot to mention that I want to sort it by time, meaning that the data that is added first to the Database appears first

Comment: Ok, since Date implements Comparable<Date>, it is as easy as:
date1.compareTo(date2);

Comment: sorry sir , can you please share me the code and where should I put it ?  I'm still beginner ):

Comment: Could you please edit the question and paste your class location? :)

Comment: Ok ,  I added it

Comment: Ok, i think you should add a new attribute to location class in order to save the date. Probably an attribute called  `timestamp`. after you add the new attribute you'll be able to order your list using  `comparator` :)

Comment: Ok , thank you so much